# Converting more than one image to binary with just one method

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

For my Little application, i have written a method to convert an image to binary and then save it in database. What i want to do now , is to find of way of making that same method be reuseable by other fileUpload. Which means, if i have two fileUploads eg.

Image 1

```
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="image2">Image 2</label>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="Upload2" runat="server" ForeColor="Blue" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

i should be able to modify the method below to process the the images without having to rewrite the method again

```
 private byte[]ConvertImage()
        {

            byte[] bytes = null;
           // byte[] bytes2 = null;
            try
            {

                HttpPostedFile postedFile = Upload1.PostedFile;


                string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
                int filesize = postedFile.ContentLength;

                Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
                BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);

                bytes = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                return bytes;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }


        }
```

The above code is what i'm using to just one fileUpload but i want to use it two without having to rewrite the whole code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract the common code into a function:

```
private void ConvertImages() {
  try {
    //Process first file.
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = Upload1.PostedFile;
    byte[] ReadImage(postedFile);
    //Now do whatever you want with first file. Maybe save it?

    //Process second file.
    postedFile = Upload2.PostedFile;
    byte[] ReadImage(postedFile);
    //Now do whatever you want with second file. Maybe save it?

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    //Handle exceptions.
  }
}

private byte[] ReadImage(HttpPostedFile postedFile) {
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    int filesize = postedFile.ContentLength;

    Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);

    return binaryreader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

private byte[]ConvertImage(FileUpload file)
        {

```
        byte[] bytes = null;
       // byte[] bytes2 = null;
        try
        {

            HttpPostedFile postedFile = file.PostedFile;


            string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            int filesize = postedFile.ContentLength;

            Stream stream = postedFile.InputStream;
            BinaryReader binaryreader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            bytes = binaryreader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            return bytes;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }


    }
```

that's all i had to make it work